# How to fix SSH Key Pair and Access is denied error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I run commands in command prompt.
aws configure - I put all information nedeed and after that I run below command:
aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name MyKeyVirginaTest --query 'KeyMaterial' --output text > MyKeyVirgina.pem

And I am receiving: Access is denied.

How to fix it?

I put a link with steps. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/aws-ec2-ssh-key-pair/

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] (if you're on unix) or [su].

Answer (score 0):

Seems `access denied` is from your **AWS profile** which does not have enough permissions to create the access key.

You need to add a new policy into your IAM user.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ec2keypairaccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DeleteKeyPair"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```